httpPlatformHandler / HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway / Error Code 0x8007053d
I tried to run Python with Waitress in IIS.
enter image description here
web.config is as follows.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
                  arguments="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\waitress_server.py %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%"
                  stdoutLogEnabled="true" 
                  stdoutLogFile="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\log\log.txt">
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

However, the following gives the same error.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="test">
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

So, I suspect the following areas are responsible.
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>

enter image description here
Handler Mapping in IIS Manager registers correctly.

Resolved.
I had not set a test folder in IIS for the web application(earth icon).
